# How can I output the open3d geometry PointCloud as .pcd file?

Tags: python, opencv, point-clouds, lidar, open3d

I am converting a lidar data (in .bin format) into .pcd format with the following code

```
with open ("lidar_velodyne64.bin", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(size_float*4)
    while byte:
        x,y,z,intensity = struct.unpack("ffff", byte)
        list_pcd.append([x, y, z])
        byte = f.read(size_float*4)
np_pcd = np.asarray(list_pcd)
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
v3d = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector
pcd.points = v3d(np_pcd)
```

And trying to output 'pcd'  as a .pcd file:

```
with open("pcd_output.pcd", "wb") as pcd2:
    pickle.dump(pcd,pcd2)
```

However, I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-cde8b419d929> in <module>
      1 with open("pcd_output.pcd", "wb") as pcd2:
----> 2     pickle.dump(pcd,pcd2)

TypeError: can't pickle open3d.open3d.geometry.PointCloud objects
```

How can I output the open3d geometry PointCloud as .pcd file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried the default [`open3d.io.write_point_cloud()`](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.io.write_point_cloud.html#open3d-io-write-point-cloud) function?

According to the example [here](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/file_io.html#Point-cloud), you can use it as below:

```
import open3d as o3d
o3d.io.write_point_cloud("copy_of_fragment.pcd", pcd)
```